# How to get the GameObject's LayerMask?

Tags: c#, unity

I am currently following Unity's [2D Roguelike tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/2d-roguelike-tutorial).

In that tutorial, I have `Player`, `Enemy`, and `Wall` Prefabs, which all belong to a `Layer` called `BlockingLayer`.

The `Player` and `Enemy` Prefabs both have a script inheriting from a script called `MovingObject`.

While writing the `MovingObject` class, I was meant to write the following line of code:

```
public LayerMask blockingLayer;
```

Later on, after creating the `Player` and `Enemy` scripts and attaching them to their respective Prefabs, I was supposed to set the `blockingLayer` to `BlockingLayer` from within the editor.

I thought this was stupid, because the Prefabs already belonged to the correct `Layer`, otherwise they couldn't interact with one another, so I changed the variable to `private` and instead added the following line to the `Start()` method:

```
blockingLayer = gameObject.layer;
```

However, suddenly collisions no longer worked. The `Player` and `Enemy` could now walk through each other as well as through `Wall`s. Using the Visual Studio debugger, I noticed the following:

- Setting the `blockingLayer` via the editor yielded following value: 256.
- `gameObject.layer` has a value of 8.

Obviously, the two layers are completely different, which explains why my modification didn't work. Still, I believe that setting the `Layer` twice — once on the GameObject, and once on the script — is dumb.

How do I get the correct Layer programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll notice something about the numbers you're seeing, 8 and 256. If we look at **256** in binary, it looks like: `100000000`. That's a one, with **8** zeros! The layer is just the index in a binary integer. So, to get the mask for a specific layer, you need to left shift a 1 by that number of spaces.

```
int layerMask = 1 << layerValue;
```

If you want to combine multiple layers together, you'd OR them together.

```
int layerMask1 = 1 << layerValue1;
int layerMask2 = 1 << layerValue2;

int combinedLayerMask = layerMask1 | layerMask2;
```

Comment: How would I use layers above 8? Like the 25th layer? An int can't store 25 zeros

Comment: @Koby27 Actually, an int has 32 bits. You could also use a long with 64 bits if you want. You might be thinking of a byte, which has 8 bits.